# Eliminar los errores de validacion Laravel con JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, validación

Bien, este es el problema. Tengo una tabla con n registros y cada registro tiene un boton que abre `edit` un `modal` y en este modal hay un formulario donde se cargan los datos del usuario y desde el cual se pueden editar. Ahora, el problema es que estoy usando `validate` de laravel, para validar los campos, y funciona de maravilla. Si hay un error, la vista se recarga, el modal se abre nuevamente y debajo de cada campo muestra el error correspondiente, hasta ahi todo genial.

ESTE ES UNO DE LOS CAMPOS

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"  value="{{ old('nombre') }}" >
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <small id="nombreText" class="form-text alert text-muted">@if ($errors->has('nombre'))
        <i class="far fa-bar"></i>{{ $errors->first('nombre') }}
    @endif
    </small>
</div>
```

Mi problema es que si, supongamos, mi usuario decide cerrar ese modal y editar mejor el de otro usuario, los mensajes de error seguiran apareciendo debajo de cada input y lo que quiero hacer, con JS, es que si ellos abren otro modal, automaticamente todos los `Errors` de laravel se eliminen para que ya no aparesca el mensaje de error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Basicamente lo que necesito es una forma de eliminar la variable `errors` que es donde estan almacenados los errores del `Validate de Laravel`, y hacerlo cada vez que se presione el boton de `showModal`. Esta funcion showModal esta dentro de mi plantilla, no es un archivo externo.

Comment: Eso no debería pasarte, algo estás haciendo mal. Y eliminar los errores, la variable `errors`, no es la solución al problema que tienes.

Comment: Si hay algun error de validacion, Laravel me devuelve una variable error y vuelve a cargar el formulario. Como el formulario esta dentro de un modal, entonces ahi muestra los errores. El problema es, que pasa si mi usuario, intenta editar el cliente `A` hay un error, me los devuelve y vuelve a cargar el formulario, pero, entonces el usuario decide ya no editar `A` cierra el modal, e intente editar `B` el formulario se va a cargar con los datos de `B` pero como la variable `error` sigue presente, en el formulario aun estaran ahi. A no ser que recargue la pagina.

Comment: En este punto, los errores deberían estar a nivel de modal, no a nivel de página. Por ello es que no tendría que haber conflictos en ese sentido. ¿Cómo es que abres el modal? ¿Con alguna llamada desde Javascript o utilizando algún componente de Laravel?

Comment: si te fijas en laimagen, aparece un error que Laravel me devolvió, pero si en ese punto cierro ese modal, y luego lo vuelvo a abrir pero con los datos de otro Paciente,   estos errores seguiran ahi, porque es una variable que se encuentra cargada en la propia vista por Laravel. Lo que tengo que hacer es que al abrir de nuevo el modal, se elimine la variable `Errors` que laravel me manda.

Answer (score 0):

Ya pasó mucho tiempo espero hayas solucionado esto, pero aquí una respuesta para los que tengan este problema a futuro.

Para eliminar estos errores existen estos dos metodos  `$this->resetErrorBag();` o `$this->resetValidation();` esto es código php no JS, estos 2 metodos eliminan todos los errores que estén almacenados, lo puedes poner en una función de tu controlador, en tu componente, que se active cuando oprimas el botón cerrar del modal, o tratar de integrarlo en la vista como último recurso.